# What's another phrase to use for an empty stare or gaze?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-meaning, formality, phrase-usage

As I'm typing it in the prompt, currently: " The maiden's gaze, empty with no musing, as her thoughts became nil. " Hope there's a better way I can emphasize her dead gaze.

Comment: First you need a verb.

Comment: Perhaps: *The **maiden gazed, emptily and without** musing, as her thoughts became nil.* I'm not sure why there's a need to come up with a different phrase. Instead, just convert your noun into a verb. Or maybe: *The maiden's **dead gaze was without thought***. Just use *dead gaze* itself.

Comment: Sounds much better; but in any case, would there be a better replacement for, ' _empty with no musing_? '

Comment: "Blank stare" is a very common idiom.

Comment: Ditto re *vacant stare* as suggested by @Runk. No one home anymore.

Comment: There's a general rule that you are better off showing not telling. Telling is reporting about the activity - her empty gaze. Showing is spelling out what the senses can sense - her eyes glazed over, or her face did not move, she had no words. Instead of telling us what the picture means to you, you show us the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Some similar adjectives which form collocations before "gaze" are the following:
vacant,
lifeless,
unseeing,
faded,
somber,
and expressionless.

Maybe they will be of help.

Source: the Corpus of Contemporary American English

Answer (score 0):

If the emptiness comes from a lack of feeling, or an inability to  show feeling, there’s **without affect**. This is a term used more in medical settings than in general language, so its use depends on the tone you want to establish.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affect_(psychology)

*Her expression was completely vacant* describes what you can see externally.

*She gazed at him without affect* tells the reader that your character is not feeling an emotion towards the person she is looking at. It also suggests that the narrator has knowledge of the character’s emotional state, but is distant and not strongly involved with the character emotionally.